# Problemas de Envio de email html e php ( via outlook), limitando mensagem

Tags: php, html, outlook

Estou com um problema qto a enviar emails via php e Html, tem um botão que abre o outlook ja com os campos de email, assunto e cc preenchidos, no corpo do email vem ja preenchido tbem com as informações, porém é como se limitasse , o texto não sai completo, ele limita e corta pela metade das informações do email no corpo, que vem de um formulario.

as informações vem de "action="mailto:" e o corpo de um texto ja fixado com variaveis que podem ser adicionadas mais informações ao texto padrão atravez de um modal

Comment: Robson, poderia colocar parte do código para entendermos como esta sendo enviado as informações para o outlook?

Comment: <div class="modal fade" id="edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header btn-primary">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">Mensagem</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">

Comment: <textarea rows="30" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Monte um Email aqui!!!">

Comment: ESSE É o modal que tem no final com o texto pre definido e depois ao final dele 
<?php 
echo 
"
TEXTO DEFINIDO
?>

Comment: ate um certo limite o texto sai completo, com assinatura e tudo, se aumentar algumas linhas ja corta o texto e não sai mais assinatura, pelo chrome ja nem envia mais e no mozila corta, sabe se tem algum limite ?

Comment: e para preencher o resto 
<form role="form" method="POST" action="mailto:<?php echo $EmailAgGit.$sremail;?>?cc=<?php echo $EmailCt;?>;&bcc=;&subject=<?php echo "$numcham  | Queda de Energia | Unidade: $unid" ;?>" enctype="text/plain">